# How to make a CreateOnly view in Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

How can I create a "Create Only" view? I just want to allow the user to create an Object and nothing else.

My current code looks like that:

## views.py

```
class BookingRequestCreateViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = BookingRequestSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return None
```

This works fine. But I have in my Model a ForeignKey and in the web view every user can see all id's. (Select input for the ForeignKey in the REST web interface)

[image]

How can I stop this behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a related field (`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, `SlugRelatedField`, etc.) is rendered with a default **HTML select**. Check this [snippet](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/c052a86c7b8ebc8159582dafaea3f6cf4a8c40f5/rest_framework/renderers.py#L313).

Django REST framework allows you to change the rendering style of a serializer field by using the `style` keyword argument (check this [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#field-styles)).

If you do not want the API to display the IDs of existing objects within a select, change the `style` argument of your serializer field, setting your rendering style to a simple **HTML input**. Something like this:

```
class BookingRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    related_field = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=RelatedModel.objects.all(),
        style={'base_template': 'input.html'},
    )
```